# How to solve a system of two differential equations describing the concentration in a leaky tank?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> While filling up a chemicals container at a constant rate of $300\,\rm L/min$, the crew of a naval ship discover two leakages at the bottom of the container. They discover that the chemical is leaking out of the first hole at a rate proportional to the square of the amount of chemical currently in the container while chemical is leaking out of the second hole at a rate proportional to the amount of chemical currently in the container.
>
> The container already had $200\,\rm L$ of the chemical before they began filling. Let $t$ ($\rm min$) be the time since the crew started filling the container and let $C(t)$ be the number of litres of chemical in the container at time $t$.
>
> Write down, but do not solve, the differential equation for $C(t)$ along with its initial condition.

So far I have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dW(t)}{\mathrm dt} &= W_\mathrm{in} - W_\mathrm{out} \\
W_\mathrm{out} &= kW^2 + W
\end{align}
$$

where $k$ is constant of proportionality. Therefore

$$\frac{\mathrm dW(t)}{\mathrm dt}= W_\mathrm{in} - kW^2 + W$$

Am I wrong? Can I get some help to complete?

Comment: I bet this question is not as easy, but do I at least have a good start?